# How to get sort value on Gridview Yii

Tags: php, jquery, sorting, gridview, yii

`$this->widget(
        'bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',
            array(
            'id'               => 'birthday-report-grid',
            'dataProvider'     => $model->search(),
            'selectableRows'   => 0,
            'ajaxType'          =>'get',
            'template'         => GridHelper::getTemplate(),
            'type'             => GridHelper::getType(),
            'enablePagination' => TRUE,
            'enableSorting'    => TRUE,
            'filter'           => $model,
            'pager'            => GridHelper::getPager(),
            'columns'          => array(
                array(
                    'header' => Yii::t('backend', 'Customer Name'),
                    'name'  => 'fullname',
                    'type' =>'raw',
                    'value'     => '$data["customer_id"] ? CHtml::link($data->getCompleteName(),array("/admin/customer/profile/".$data["customer_id"]."/dashboard")) : $data->getCompleteName()',
                    'filter'=>CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'fullname').CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'month', array('id'=>'Filmonth','style' => 'Display:none;')),
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'email',
                    'header' => Yii::t('backend', 'Customer Email'),
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'birthday_month',
                    'value' => '!empty($data->birthday_month) && $data->birthday_month > 0 ? date("F", strtotime("1-".$data->birthday_month."-1970")) : ""',
                    'filter' => false,
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'primary_phone',
                    'header' => Yii::t('backend', 'Customer Contact'),
                    'filter' => false,
                ),
                array(
                    'header' => Yii::t('backend', 'Total Order (To Date)'),
                    'value' => '$data->getNoOfOrder2()',
                    'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'text-align: right'),
                    'footer' => '<div style="text-align: right">'.$model->getTotalOfOrder().'</div>',
                ),
                array(
                    'header' => Yii::t('backend', 'Total Order Amount (To Date)'),
                    'value' => 'CurrencyHelper::formatPrice($data->getTotalAmountOfOrderByCustomerId2())',
                    'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'text-align: right'),
                    'footer' => '<div style="text-align: right">'.CurrencyHelper::formatPrice($model->getGrandTotalAmountOrder()).'</div>',
                ),
            )
        )
    );`

WHat i want is how to get sort value (Example: sort=fullname) what i want is "fullname"

i mean when i click column sorting on Customer Fullname , i can get the sort value using **Jquery**
Example image:
[When Click sorting on "Customer Fullname" i need get sorting value (sort="VALUE")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1AdD.png)
Please help me thanks